# Airflow no module named 'kubernetes'

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

## Answer My Own Question

I recently upgraded to Airflow 1.10 which introduced the `KubernetesPodOperator` however whenever I use it I see the following error in the webserver: `No module named 'kubernetes'`. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This happens because the kubernetes library isn't installed with vanilla airflow. You can fix this by running `pip install "apache-airflow[kubernetes]"`.

Comment: i got same error upgrading from 1.10.3 to 1.10.4 but that pip install suggestion does not fix it :(

Answer (score 2):

For airflow 1.10.4,

```
pip install 'apache-airflow[cncf.kubernetes]'
```